# Error when trying to get the length of a variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, string-length

I have a header method that write a standard header to all text files I throw it's way.  Here's the code:

```
def header(file, description)
    File.open(file, 'w') do |out|
        out.puts ".------------------------------------------------------------------------."
        out.puts "| File generated by: " + Etc.getlogin() + " " * (52-Etc.getlogin().length) + "|"
        out.puts "| File generated at: " + Time.now().to_s() + "                           |"
        out.puts ".------------------------------------------------------------------------."
        out.puts "| DESCRIPTION:                                                           |"
        out.puts "| " + description.to_s + " " * (70-description.length) + "|"
        out.puts "|                                                                        |"
        out.puts "'------------------------------------------------------------------------'"
        out.puts "=====FINDINGS====="
    end
end
```

So when I run the following call statement:

```
 header('01httpserver.txt', "This file details all configuration files with where http servers are concerned.")
```

I get the following error:

```
cis.rb:63:in `*': negative argument (ArgumentError)
    from cis.rb:63:in `block in header'
    from cis.rb:57:in `open'
    from cis.rb:57:in `header'
    from cis.rb:70:in `<main>'
```

Line 63 is this line:

```
out.puts "| " + description.to_s + " " * (70-description.length) + "|"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do string padding, which it seems you're doing here, why not use the `sprint` notation?

```
out.puts "| %-70s|" % description.to_s
```

This uses the [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25) method.
The `%-70s` means pad string to 70 spaces, left aligned. Without `-` it is right aligned.

Any values that are too long will overflow this spot. To handle that:

```
out.puts "| %-70s|" % description.to_s[0,70]
```

That should limit it to the first 70 characters. Within the Rails environment there's a method called [`truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) that can add on an ellipsis to show truncation occurred.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your description is longer than 70 characters and so you're multiplying the string by a negative value, which is not allowed.

To fix it change the line with the error to this:

```
out.puts "| " + description.to_s + " " * [0, (70-description.length)].max + "|"
```